# Where can I see Taproot scripts?

Tags: script, taproot, blockchain-explorer

I am trying to look more into Taproot scripts and was wondering if someone could help me on how to access them? I was thinking of using a blockchain explorer that decodes Taproot scripts but I can't seem to find any.

Comment: @Pieter Wuille how were able to tell what is an output and input. I thought they were all inputs because of the red arrow.

Comment: I didn't use mempool.space to inspect the transaction, but on that website: inputs are on the left (and have a red arrow before the address) while outputs are on the right (and have a red arrow after the address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does e.g. the "Details" button on Mempool.space satisfy your inquiry?

[image: Calling up the details on Mempool.space shows the leaf script in detail in detail.]

Comment: mempool.space doesn't support searching for Taproot (P2TR) addresses/spends does it? You need to know transactions that are spending from P2TR addresses.

Comment: And Bitcoin Core decodescript RPC can do that also (Pieter comment on another post)

Comment: Mempool.space recently added the mempool goggles that allow you to filter transactions in future blocks by various criteria: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk9ca.png

Comment: Neat, not currently live on the site right? I can't click on the next predicted block to be mined I don't think.

Comment: Just click the upcoming block: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBUUb.png

Comment: Strange, I'm clicking on it and nothing is happening. Never mind, thanks.

Comment: I click the upcoming block (note that it is on the right if you swapped directions), which then pops up the "Next Block" view. When I hover over the content of the next block, the mempool goggles are shown in the top left of the square (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYwRL.png). Click the goggles to get access to the filters. If you don’t see it, perhaps you forbid Javascript on mempool.space?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a blockchain explorer for Taproot scripts, there's [scriptpath.info](https://scriptpath.info/) (disclaimer: I created it). It only shows transactions that spend Taproot script path inputs, decodes their scripts and gives some additional information. However, it doesn't allow you to search through the transactions in any way.

For any meaningful analysis you'll probably have to resort to reading the blockchain from a local node and extracting the Taproot scripts yourself (how to do that you can find out in other answers on this site, or you can just read [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki)).

Comment: So for this transaction:
https://mempool.space/tx/b8ef0b668eafb0f03f11c3af6ed7024a69c5f10a482e239b1179b8b293baa831 
There is no Tapscript right? Even though they use P2TR.

Comment: @mark That transaction has two P2TR outputs, but only a P2WPKH input. P2TR outputs can be spent using just a signature ("key path spending") or by satisfying a script ("script path spending"), but the distinction only exists at *spending* time. As the transaction you link to has no P2TR inputs, there is nothing to say about it.

Answer (score -1):

Taproot has evened the playing field. Bitcoin now has a clear path to deployment of smart contracts, decentralized autonomous organizations, and more. Products like the Lightning Network have already shown that fast and reliable transactions can still be backed with an immutable ledger, even without the access that Taproot will give developers of the future.